# Fusion Table Google Maps Second Javascript Drop-Down Menu not working

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Right now I am currently creating a map that will have a javascript menu allowing users to change to different map views using the Google fusion table overlays. My first dropdown menu works like a charm. However, the second dropdown menu will not work with the other. I would like the two to work together. For example, someone could select "Animals" and "Opportunity" and it would show locations with the cell data "Animals" and "Opportunity."

This is my Google Maps HTML Page:

```
        <html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Met Sacramento Internship Map</title> 

<!-- Style --> 
<style> 
  body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  #map_canvas { height: 500px; width:600px; }
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableid = 567682;
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(567682); 

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.59970036588819, -121.541748046875);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
          layer.setMap(map);
  }
    //Change the query based on the user's selection
function interestMap(interest) {
 layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Interest Area' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Interest Area' CONTAINS '" + interest + "'"); 
}
function statusMap(status) {
 layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Status' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Status' CONTAINS '" + status + "'"); 
}
</script>

 </script> 

</head> 
<body onload="initialize();">  
  Internship Status <select onchange="interestMap(this.value);"> 
    <option value="">Interest Areas</option>
<option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
<option value="Animals">Animals</option>
<option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
<option value="Art/Music/Theatre">Art/Music/Theatre</option>
<option value="Athletics and Martial Arts">Athletics</option>
<option value="Automotive and Transportation">Automotive</option>
<option value="Bicycles">Bicycles</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
<option value="Community Development">Community Development</option>
<option value="Computers">Computers</option>
<option value="Cosmetology">Cosmetology</option>
<option value="Culinary">Culinary</option>
<option value="Education">Education</option>
<option value="Government and Politics">Politics</option>
<option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
<option value="Hospitality/Tourism/Event Planning">Event Planning</option>
<option value="Law and Public Safety">Law and Public Safety</option>
<option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
<option value="Media and Information Technology">Media</option>
<option value="Photography">Photography</option>
<option value="Science and Technology">Science and Technology
</option>
<option value="Social Services">Social Services</option>
  </select>
   Status <select onchange="statusMap(this.value);"> 
    <option value="">Status</option>
<option value="BEING PURSUED">Being Pursued</option>
<option value="HAS INTERN">Has Intern</option>
<option value="NOT TAKING">Not Taking</option>
<option value="OPPORTUNITY">Opportunity</option>
<option value="OVER 18">Over 18</option>
<option value="POTENTIAL?">Potential</option>
<option value="SEE NOTES">See Notes</option>


  </select>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the:
[Fusion Table](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=567682)

Here is the: 
[Live Code](http://kynikosdesign.com/ltimaps/)

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You're doing the queries separate from each other. Consider adding a button to trigger one data query using the selected values.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further, I am somewhat new to JavaScript. I am guessing you mean to turn function interestMap and function statusMap into one triggering button. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution - tested in Chrome ;) - note the new button, refreshFusion method and the id attributes on the two select elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Met Sacramento Internship Map</title> 

<!-- Style --> 
<style> 
  body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  #map_canvas { height: 500px; width:600px; }
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableid = 567682;
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(567682); 

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.59970036588819, -121.541748046875);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
          layer.setMap(map);
  }

    function refreshFusion() {
        var qry = "SELECT Address, 'Status' FROM " + tableid;
        var interest = document.getElementById('ddlInterest').value;
        var status = document.getElementById('ddlStatus').value;
        var filters = [];
        if(interest != '') {
            filters.push("'Interest Area' CONTAINS '" + interest + "'");
        }
        if(status != '') {
            filters.push("'Status' CONTAINS '" + status + "'");
        }
        if(filters.length > 0) {
            qry += " WHERE " + filters.join(" AND ");
        }
        layer.setQuery(qry);
    }
</script>

 </script> 

</head> 
<body onload="initialize();">  
  <p>Internship Status <select id="ddlInterest"> 
    <option value="">Interest Areas</option>
<option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
<option value="Animals">Animals</option>
<option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
<option value="Art/Music/Theatre">Art/Music/Theatre</option>
<option value="Athletics and Martial Arts">Athletics</option>
<option value="Automotive and Transportation">Automotive</option>
<option value="Bicycles">Bicycles</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
<option value="Community Development">Community Development</option>
<option value="Computers">Computers</option>
<option value="Cosmetology">Cosmetology</option>
<option value="Culinary">Culinary</option>
<option value="Education">Education</option>
<option value="Government and Politics">Politics</option>
<option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
<option value="Hospitality/Tourism/Event Planning">Event Planning</option>
<option value="Law and Public Safety">Law and Public Safety</option>
<option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
<option value="Media and Information Technology">Media</option>
<option value="Photography">Photography</option>
<option value="Science and Technology">Science and Technology
</option>
<option value="Social Services">Social Services</option>
  </select>
   Status <select id="ddlStatus"> 
    <option value="">Status</option>
<option value="BEING PURSUED">Being Pursued</option>
<option value="HAS INTERN">Has Intern</option>
<option value="NOT TAKING">Not Taking</option>
<option value="OPPORTUNITY">Opportunity</option>
<option value="OVER 18">Over 18</option>
<option value="POTENTIAL?">Potential</option>
<option value="SEE NOTES">See Notes</option>


  </select> <input type="button" value="Run Query" onclick="refreshFusion();" /></p>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! This worked like a charm. One question, is there no way to do this without the button to query the results?

Comment: You could remove the button and add `onchange="refreshFusion();"` to the select elements. *tested in FF*